# Angular2 how to empty observable stream

Tags: http, typescript, angular, observable

I am using Angular 2.0.0-beta.0 and TypeScript 1.7.5

When you type something in the search box and something is found and shown on the screen, then you delete the search input box and you want to show an empty list. It work using this piece of code:
`this.searchTermStream.next("makesureyoudontfindanything");`

Does anyone has a better cleaner solution without doing a http request?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'contact-search',
    template: `
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputUser">Search</label>
                <input #inputUser (keyup)="search(inputUser.value)">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="#contact of contactList | async">{{contact.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `
})

export class ContactSearch {

    private searchTermStream = new Subject<string>();

    private contactList: Observable<Contact[]> = this.searchTermStream
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap((value: string) => this.contactService.searchContacts(value))

    constructor(private contactService: ContactService) {}

    search(value: string) {
        if (value) {
            this.searchTermStream.next(value);
        }
        else {
            this.searchTermStream.next("makesureyoudontfindanything");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if value is empty before calling service:

```
private contactList: Observable<Contact[]> = this.searchTermStream
    .debounceTime(300)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap((value: string) => 
       0 < value.length ? this.contactService.searchContacts(value) : Observable.of([]))

search(value: string) {
    this.searchTermStream.next(value);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this just leave the last found values in the contactList when deleting the input?